# Route websocket data through USB link to PC client (Android)

Tags: websocket, android-ndk, usb, adb, portforwarding

I have an issue where WiFi is not available on an Android device. We want to stream image data from the device using a websocket server (written using WebSocket++) through to the PC. However, I'm not sure if this is possible without operational WiFi. So, the position we are in is that we may only have the USB link available.

Someone today suggested we might be able to get Websockets working using adb port forwarding (see https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#forwardports), but I'm not sure if that's correct. Could this work, and what would that solution look like?

Are there any other reasonable options. I'm not certain if tethering is available on the device and if that could be another solution?

Comment: One thing I'd appreciate someone clarifying is whether adb acts in a manner where it provides a usb based 'tunnel' between host and client and port forwarding just marshals traffic into this tunnel and back out again to the mapped port (e.g. using some form of proxy)? I have spent a fair bit of time looking for detailed info on how adb port forwarding works under the hood but can't find any great references that are any more detailed than the adb android documentation. I'm less interested in the port forwarding side as and more interested in how the data is marshalled under the hood.

Comment: Update using adb forward does work and enables the websocket traffic to route via USB to the PC client. e.g. adb forward tcp:80 tcp:80